# SFTP, limit download data for specific user

Tags: linux, ftp, limitations

I was wondering if a root user can create another user with a specified limit of data to download from server (i.e.: from Filezilla).

Server is Debian 7

Comment: AFAIK OpenSSH (the most common SSH daemon) has no built-in rate-limiting functions.  So you are left with trying to hack together something that will be executed after the user connects.  You might be able to get pam to execute some commands when a user is authorized to apply traffic shaping rules.

Comment: Are you looking to rate limit the connection or limit the total amount of data the user can download?

Comment: I'm looking to limit the connection, but limit the total amount of data will work as well . Thanks

Comment: What protocol are you going to use for download (SFTP/FTP)? What SFTP/FTP server are you using?

Comment: I use only sftp, i'm running debian 7, and I use the default sftp server preinstalled